# Background image is not showing up in div

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I have tried everything and cannot figure out why I cannot get the background image to show up for this div.

```
**Here is the code:**
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#top {
  background-image: url(../IMG/PINS.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST BCKGRND IMAGE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top">


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The file structure is set up like this: I have a main folder called TEST_SITE, inside of that folder I have a folder for my CSS and a folder for my images called IMG.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the background image is not showing up.

If anyone can please give me a heads up as to what might be wrong, I would truly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the height of the `#top` div is important: if you set the width, and then the height to auto, then the background still won't show because there is nothing within the div to put a background to. However, if you force a height by setting one in the css, then the background will show. 
The code you have given for your path is incorrect because the `background-image` expects only a path to an image (and nothing else), whereas what you have given is suited to the `background`.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/6uctsra0/)

Comment: Happy to be of assistance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a height and width value from the `#top` and use the `background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat;` like my answer: for example

```
#top{
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   background-image: url(YOUR IMAGE PATH); 
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:center center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

or you can make it like this:

```
#top{ 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background:url(YOUR IMAGE PATH) no-repeat fixed center; 
   width:500px;height:500px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your div is empty. If you add content to it then you will see the background. You can also set a height or add padding with CSS.

```
<div id="top">
 <p>A large amount of text here</p>
</div>
```

or

```
#top{
 height:400px;
 background-image: url(yourimagehere); 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

or

```
#top{
 padding: 25px 0;
 background-image: url(yourimagehere); 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```